# Include markdown file in style guide without associated component file?

Tags: react-styleguidist

Is there a way to include markdown files in styleguidist that don't have an associated React component file?

Right now I'm using dummy components to accomplish this but I'm wondering if there is a better way? I'm also hiding the dummy component's path (via `getComponentPathLine()` in the config) so that it doesn't appear like a component in the style guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style guide config:

```
module.exports = {
  sections: [
    {
      name: 'Introduction',
      content: 'docs/introduction.md'
    }
  ]
}
```

See more examples [in the docs](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/components.html#sections).